# Give Jenkins User Access to Keychain

Tags: macos, jenkins

I am working with jenkins as a daemon user located in /Users/Shared/jenkins on osx. When I attempt to build, I run into the error:

```
security: SecKeychainUnlock /Users/build/Library/Keychains/login.keychain: write permissions error
FATAL: Unable to unlock the keychain.
```

My default user is "build", and build's login keychain holds all the Apple certificates needed for code signing. I have specified under the jenkins system settings the location of the keychain and the password needed to access it, but permission is still denied. I have tried solutions from many of the stackoverflow posts on this topic already and are still not finding success, so any advice is helpful. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Getting crazy to find an answer. Have you posted this question somewhere else? I'm tracking all active questions